# Equivalent of date("c") , hash_hmac('sha512', "str1", "str2") and pack("H*", $secretkey) in elixir

Tags: php, elixir

What would be the equivalent of PHP's `date("c")`, `hash_hmac('sha512', "str1", "str2")`, and `pack("H*", $secretkey)` in Elixir?

I want to convert this to elixir code

```
$binKey = pack("H*", $hmackey);
$hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $msg, $binKey));
```

Comment: Could you mention what language these statements are coming from? Is it PHP?

Comment: it's from PHP @kaikuchn

Comment: [How does one generate an HMAC string in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082396/how-does-one-generate-an-hmac-string-in-elixir)

Comment: Cross-post https://elixirforum.com/t/code-from-php-to-elixir/47863

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any PHP but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783996/format-date-with-elixir) someone already asked how to format a date. If you want ISO8601 as the output [it's super easy](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Date.html#to_iso8601/2) (`Date.utc_today() |> Date.to_iso8601()`).

Elixir does not provide HMAC hashing in its standard library as far as I know. But you can use the Erlang function: `:crypto.hash/2` E.g., `:crypto.hash(:sha512, "text")`. See the [Erlang crypto docs](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#hash-2). Note that I'm unsure about what hash_hmac does exactly. If you want a Message Authentication Code, look into the `:crypto.mac/3` function.

As for `pack("H*", $secretkey)` is that converting an integer to a string in hexadecimal representation? If that's the case, then `secret_key |> Integer.to_string(16)` is what you want.

---

After your comment I assume this is what you want to copy and paste:

```
hmac_key = "deadbeef"
msg = "your message to sign"
bin_key = hmac_key |> String.to_integer(16)
:crypto.mac(:hmac, :sha512, msg, bin_key) |> Base.encode16()
```

Obviously you'll still need to substitute `msg` and `hmac_key` with your values.

Comment: This don't run for me

Comment: $binKey = pack("H*", $hmackey);
$hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $msg, $binKey));

This is the code that I want to convert to Elixir

Comment: I appended a copy&paste ready code block, this should be what you want.

Comment: I've tried this code but this raise an error, I don't know how to do this in Elixir

Comment: Do we really need the bin_key step? It seems to me one can simply call `:crypto.mac(:hmac, :sha512, msg, hmac_key)`.

Comment: @bortzmeyer it would be a very different key though. It looks like the key is provided as a hex string in the original code. Not knowing anything else about the system I really can't say what's unnecessary here. That's something the OP would need to think about.

OP, what's the error you are getting? The above code works for me..?